# How can I use Sequelize and SQLite3 with NWJS 0.28.0?

Tags: node.js, orm, sqlite, node-webkit

NWJS version 0.28.0 runs with NodeJS v9.4 and SQlite3 package is only compatible up to v7.x.

How can I use SQLite and Sequelize with v0.28?

The command I have to compile SQlite is

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=""
```

But no matter which target I put I got errors.

If there is no way of doing so, which ORM/database could I use for a library management app (songs, books, fonts, icons, etc). The database could get huge.

Thanks!

EDIT output:

```
> sqlite3@3.1.13 install /media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 response downloading http://node-webkit.s3.amazonaws.com/v9.4.0/nw-headers-v9.4.0.tar.gz
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/nw-gyp/lib/install.js:216:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/nw-gyp/node_modules/request/request.js:1068:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:551:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/jer/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node" "/usr/bin/nw-gyp" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-webkit-v9.4.0-linux-ia32/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-webkit-v9.4.0-linux-ia32"
gyp ERR! cwd /media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! nw-gyp -v v3.6.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'nw-gyp configure --fallback-to-build --module=/media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-webkit-v9.4.0-linux-ia32/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-webkit-v9.4.0-linux-ia32' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/home/jer/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node" "/media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.38
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute 'nw-gyp configure --fallback-to-build --module=/media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-webkit-v9.4.0-linux-ia32/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/media/DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/NJS-Player/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-webkit-v9.4.0-linux-ia32' (1)
npm WARN njs-player@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN njs-player@0.0.1 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.13 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: I noticed the 404 error but even when I specify a "valid" version it doesn't work. What does it take to use sqlite3 on node grr

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved this by now, but in case others come along that have the same issue, here's how I solved it.

The basic problem is that sequelize does a require on 'sqlite3', and that's going to get imported from node_modules automatically.

The rub is, this breaks the whole "npm install" thing, because now you have this long command line you have to enter in order to properly build sqlite for nwjs. So, if you delete your node_modules, you have to remember every time to do this dance, which is annoying.

Unfortunately, we can't just checkout sqlite3 and build it and require from a local folder, because of the way sequelize is requireing it, it *must* go into node_modules.

At the same time, once we've built the correct binary, we sort of want to keep it around because we're going to need to distribute it with our app. But it's super bad to check all of node modules into git. We could solve this with a git exclusion, but what if we want to change the version of nwjs? Same deal, have to remember each time to build sqlite3 and what all those command line options are. Ugh.

So, the simple solution is to just check out sqlite3 somewhere into your project where it'll get stored by git when you commit. Then take a look at the package.json, and change the install script to:

`"scripts": {
    "install": "node-pre-gyp install --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target-arch=x64 --target=0.31.5",
    "pretest": "node test/support/createdb.js",
    "test": "mocha -R spec --timeout 480000"
  },`

Substitute your own arch and target there.

Now, go back to the root of your project and npm install from the path you put sqlite3.

Something like: 

`npm install ./sqlite3 --save`

This will cause everything to rebuild using the correct nwjs version and the correct binaries/path etc... and add a file: reference to your package.json, so that the next time you need to wipe out node_modules and do an npm install, everything will Just Work.

Update:
Browsing through the source code of sequelize, I also came across this:

`try {
      if (sequelize.config.dialectModulePath) {
        this.lib = require(sequelize.config.dialectModulePath).verbose();
      } else {
        this.lib = require('sqlite3').verbose();
      }`

So it looks like you can pass dialectModulePath as an option to sequelize config and manually specify the module you want to load, so that might help. I couldn't find anywhere in the official docs that mention it, and I haven't tested it personally, so YMMV.